# How to display text in the second and third xml element which have the same name using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to know if I can display the names by using the values of the xml part using xslt. If that is not possible then how would I simply display the names using xslt? I would also like to know can xslt change an element name in the xml?

My xml is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="myxmltest.xsl type="text/xsl" version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" ?>

<x>
 <y>
  <z value="mike"></z>
  <z value="john"></z>
  <z value="dave"></z>
 </y>
</x>
```

My xsl is this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="z">
<xsl:apply-templates select="z[1]" />mike
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="z">
<xsl:apply-templates select="z[2]" />john
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="z">
<xsl:apply-templates select="z[3]" />dave
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Desired result in the xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="myxmltest.xsl type="text/xsl" version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" ?>

<boss>
 <manager>
  <employee value="mike">mike</employee>
  <employee value="john">john</employee>
  <employee value="dave">dave</employee>
 </manager>
</boss>
```

Comment: What is the exact result you're hoping to get?

Comment: The desired result is <x> changes to <boss> and <y> changes to <manager> and <z> changes to <employee> where in <employee> the names mike, john, and dave are displayed in the browser.

Comment: There is no way to isolate "boss", "manager", "employee" or other in your XML and the XSL lends us no help here. As it stands thus just outputs "dave dave dave"

Comment: I was able to get the correct output by making a table in the xslt, but I want to know if there is a way to override xml tags as in <x> changes to <boss>? I have just started experimenting with xml 5 hours before my post. I am very new to this and I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: @Kenny Your two requirements do not go together. If you want to display the result in a browser, then make your output html and show the values in a table (if that's the preferable format). Changing element names only makes sense if your output is XML - but then it makes no sense to display it in a browser.

Comment: Thank you Michael.hor that is perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result you show can be easily accomplished by:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="x">
    <boss>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </boss>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="y">
    <manager>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </manager>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="z">
    <employee value="{@value}">
        <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
    </employee>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```